# Query with date filter in Node.js is failing

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, datetime

I am trying to run a simple query with date filter in node.js, even though running the same query from workbench I am getting the data but while running from Node, no rows are returned.

```
const fetchHistoricalDataQuery = 'SELECT timestamp, \
meter_id   AS meterId, \
txn_info_1 AS meterReading, \
txn_info_2 AS txnInfo2, \
txn_info_3 AS txnInfo3, \
txn_info_4 AS txnInfo4, \
txn_info_5 AS txnInfo5, \
date       date \
FROM   si_agent.historical_data \
WHERE date = ?';

jp_db.fetchHistoricalData = (date) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(fetchHistoricalDataQuery, [date], (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                return resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This is returning no rows when I am passing the input as: "2020-03-21 00:00:00"

**whereas running the same query in mysql workbench is giving me the expected response.**

```
SELECT timestamp, 
meter_id   AS meterId, 
txn_info_1 AS meterReading, 
txn_info_2 AS txnInfo2, 
txn_info_3 AS txnInfo3, 
txn_info_4 AS txnInfo4, 
txn_info_5 AS txnInfo5, 
date       date 
FROM   si_agent.historical_data 
WHERE date = "2020-03-21 00:00:00"
```

**Any Idea on why this could be happening?**

**EDIT:**

I tried sending the whole Date object - did not work. new date("2020-03-21 00:00:00")

Comment: Not related, but note that any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2) you have to question whether your schema design is optimal

Comment: I don't think that calling your column date and timestampo is a very good idea, did you try to run the query with backticks around the questionable columns?